# How do I remove green background without replacing it with another background?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency

My objective is to produce a foreground video clip with a transparent background, that can be superimposed on any background video. I know how to remove the background using compositor, by replacing it with another background, but when I try to replace the green background with a transparent one produced in Gimp, I get a black silhouette in place of the foreground image.
I am using Blender 2.82, Windows 10 Home, working with 30 fps, rendering to ffmpeg. No audio yet, although the future plan is to have foreground with audio.
So far, I have only used Blender VSE at a basic level, and just starting with compositor. I am new to video editing, and  so step by step instruction would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked perfectly.

Comment: Go over some tutorials first: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqJb1AwUu-wh61cLWMBVWS3N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this Explanation i will use a clip of an alpaca on a greenscreen from here -
https://www.videvo.net/video/alpaca-on-green-screen/3442/

**Step one - setup**

Open blender with the General preset
[image]

And select the Compositing workspace
[image]

Select use nodes
[image]

**Step two - add nodes**

Remove The render Layers node by clicking it and pressing X on the keyboard
[image]

Add a Movie Clip node by clicking the add menu

[image]

Select the sub-menu Matte

[image]

And select Keying and drag the node to left of the Composite node

[image]

Add Movie Clip Node with Add -> Input -> Movie clip

[image]

[image]

Click Open On the Movie Clip node and select the video clip

Add a Viewer node with Add -> Output -> Viewer

[image]

and place it under composite node

[image]

click the yellow circle on the movie clip node and drag the mouse to the Image input on the left of the Keying node and connect all the other nodes as in the image

[image]

you will notice the clip in the background
Click V on your keyboard a few times to zoom out or Alt+V to zoom in so that you can clearly see your video.

**Step three - Keying node**

Select a frame in which there is a subject on the greenscreen
By changing the frame
[image]

Click The Color Input on the keying node

[image]

Click The eyedropper icon

[image]

And Click The Green on your image if there are darker and lighter areas click somewhere in the middle

[image]

you will see the green vanish but it won't be perfect every time so we will tweak some settings

Set The Feather Distance to about 2 or 3 pixels

[image]

Then Change the Dilate/Erode to some negative number that doesn't cut away from the character
[image]

Play with settings until it looks right

**Step four - render**

First set the End to the last frame of your shot which you can find by changing the frame
[image]

on the right select the output properties

[image]

Make sure the file format is set to png
and RGBA

[image]

Press the select file button

[image]

select a output folder and make sure it is empty because it will fill with images
and press accept on the bottom right

Now all you have to do is render out the animation

select it from the render dropdown and wait for it to finish.

[image]

when the image Stops changing Your Done!

You can import a image sequence in most video editing software including blender and the background is removed

**Step 4 - finish**
close blender with the big red X on the top right when it finishes rendering

Comment: Appreciate your response. I did my best with your advice, but as a newbie, I need step-by step instructions, which nodes, what do I connect to what, etc.

Comment: ok i will add step by step instructions in a little bit including the nodes. Happy to help